# How to determine if image is mostly black or is mostly white

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, opencv

I'm working on university project: my task is to recognize ARTag using Python.
I'm doing great but there is one task which I do not know how to do.

For starters I segmented ARTag for smaller lets say pixels: but those pixels are neither perfect black nor white. There are mixes of 70% white to 30% black. 
 So I want to determine if this pixel which i segmented tag is mostly black or white. Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to define a given segment color:**
Pixels take values from 0 (black) to 255 (white)
Lets call the pixels with values <= 76 - black.

Assuming that you have segment of an image with many pixels (imgSgt):

```py
    blackPxNum = np.count_nonzero([imgSgt<=76]) #number of black pixels
    whitePxNum = imgSgt.size - blackPixNumber 
    
    if blackPxNum > whitePxNum:
        """segment is black"""
        pass
```

**To threshold image** 
Take a look at these [functions](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) which allow you to convert grayscale image (pixel values from 0 to 255) to binary image (pixel value 0 or 1).